Matplotlib set min/max tick labels to be larger than data and still show 0 tick label when appropoate
I'm trying to plot some data using matplotlib and struggling to get the effect that I want without manually tuning the tick labels. I have to generate a lot of these plots, and the data changes which would be a lot of manual labor, so automation of this would be preferred. Basically, I would like the code to do ~3 things:

Set tick labels on the plots so that the min/max values of the data being shown encompassed (e.g. if the largest data point is 40, then the largest tick should be at least 40)
Set a variable number of ticks (for my use case I typically have between 3-5)
If appropriate, have one of the tick labels be 0 (where it is appropriate if the min of the data is less than 0, and the max is greater)

I have the first two working somewhat well, it's the third one that is giving me trouble. If I let matplotlib do it's thing, I get the following:
# Make the data
datax = np.arange(0.0, 11.0, 0.1)

datay1 = 10 + np.sin(datax)
datay2 = np.random.normal(0, 10.0, datax.shape)

datay = [datay1, datay2]

# Matplotlib basic
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax = axs.flatten()

for idx in range(len(ax)):
    ax[idx].scatter(datax, datay[idx])
    ax[idx].grid()

plt.tight_layout()


With this I am able to get the 0 tick label to show up on the right plot, but data is outside the biggest and smallest tick labels, and I cannot set the number of tick labels. I do like that the 0 tick label is not there on the left plot though, since adding it would unnecessarily squish everything. Making a small modification:
# Matplotlib set the ticks
num_xticks = 3
num_yticks = 5
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax = axs.flatten()

for idx in range(len(ax)):
    ax[idx].scatter(datax, datay[idx])

    # Set the ticks
    ticks_x = np.linspace(np.nanmin(datax), np.nanmax(datax), num_xticks)
    ticks_y = np.linspace(np.nanmin(datay[idx]), np.nanmax(datay[idx]), num_yticks)

    ax[idx].set_xticks(ticks_x)
    ax[idx].set_yticks(ticks_y)

    ax[idx].grid()

plt.tight_layout()



You can see that I can indeed add the ticks and the data is now well encapsulated. But I no longer get a 0 in the right plot, which is a bit awkward because grounding myself to a middle value of 1.54 is much more difficult than 0. I'm not super sure what the best way to resolve this would be, so I would appreciate any help and tips you may have! Thanks!
Edit:
I think I've found a partial solution. I don't think it's ideal because it doesn't account for uneven distributions over the 0 line. For example, with the data I showed before:
...

for idx in range(len(ax)):
    ...
    # For now, just on the y-axis
    if np.min(ticks_y) < 0.0 and np.max(ticks_y) > 0.0:
        value = np.max(np.array([np.abs(np.nanmin(datay[idx])), np.nanmax(datay[idx])]))
        ticks_y = np.linspace(-value, value, num_yticks)
...


It works rather well. But if the min of the data is much lower than the max, then the plot looks wonky
datay3 = datay2 + 10.0


Here I'd prefer for there to be more ticks in the positive y-axis than in the negative to reduce the whitespace

There may be an easier / better way to do this, but I found an exhaustive search method where we minimize the total white space that will be on the plot seems to at least return what I want for this one example. We will see how it fares under my actual use cases, but here is the code:
# Data where this isn't pretty
datay3 = datay2 + 10.0

datay = [datay1, datay3]

# Matplotlib set the ticks and make sure we see the 0
num_xticks = 3
num_yticks = 5
fig, axs = plt.subplots(1,2)
ax = axs.flatten()

for idx in range(len(ax)):
    ax[idx].scatter(datax, datay[idx])

    # Set the ticks
    ticks_x = np.linspace(np.nanmin(datax), np.nanmax(datax), num_xticks)
    ticks_y = np.linspace(np.nanmin(datay[idx]), np.nanmax(datay[idx]), num_yticks)

    # For now, just on the y-axis
    if np.min(ticks_y) < 0.0 and np.max(ticks_y) > 0.0:
        # Figure out how many ticks we want in positive and negative
        # We want to minimize the white space
        possible_positive_tick_count = np.arange(1.0, (num_yticks-2)+1, 1.0) # +1 is to get the end point
        total_white_space = []
        step_size = []

        for positive_tick_count in possible_positive_tick_count:
            # Need to figure out the biggest step size we need to accommodate since we want 
            # all the ticks to be spaced evenly
            positive_step_size = np.nanmax(datay[idx]) / positive_tick_count

            negative_tick_count = num_yticks - 1 - positive_tick_count
            negative_step_size = np.abs(np.nanmin(datay[idx])) / negative_tick_count

            curr_step_size = max(positive_step_size, negative_step_size)

            # Get the white space that we would have from this step size
            positive_max_tick = curr_step_size * positive_tick_count
            negative_max_tick = curr_step_size * negative_tick_count

            total_white_space.append(
                abs(positive_max_tick) - abs(np.nanmax(datay[idx])) + abs(negative_max_tick) - abs(np.nanmin(datay[idx]))
            )
            step_size.append(curr_step_size)
        
        # Get the minimum
        idx_chosen = total_white_space.index(min(total_white_space))
        chosen_step_size = step_size[idx_chosen]
        positive_tick_count = possible_positive_tick_count[idx_chosen]
        negative_tick_count = num_yticks - 1 - positive_tick_count

        # Create the ticks based on this
        ticks_y = np.concatenate([
            np.arange(-chosen_step_size*negative_tick_count, 0.0, chosen_step_size),
            np.arange(0.0, chosen_step_size*positive_tick_count + chosen_step_size, chosen_step_size)
        ])

    ax[idx].set_xticks(ticks_x)
    ax[idx].set_yticks(ticks_y)

    ax[idx].grid()

plt.tight_layout()



